# PowerShell: Each parameter set must have at least one parameter that is unique for that parameter set

Tags: powershell, parameters

This "rule" is stated in the PowerShell documentation, for example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd878348%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).
However, I'm not sure I'm interpreting it correctly. The following seems to work fine to me.

```
function Test-ParameterSets
{
    param(
    [Parameter(Position = 0, ParameterSetName = "NameName")] 
    [Parameter(Position = 0, ParameterSetName = "NameId")] 
    [string] $A_by_Name, 

    [Parameter(Position = 0, ParameterSetName = "IdName")] 
    [Parameter(Position = 0, ParameterSetName = "IdId")] 
    [int] $A_by_Id,

    [Parameter(Position = 1, ParameterSetName = "NameName")] 
    [Parameter(Position = 1, ParameterSetName = "IdName")] 
    [string] $B_by_Name,

    [Parameter(Position = 1, ParameterSetName = "NameId")] 
    [Parameter(Position = 1, ParameterSetName = "IdId")] 
    [int] $B_by_Id
    )

    write-host "Hello"
}
```

Have I misunderstood? Or is the rule out of date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't taken your example far enough:

```
function Test-ParameterSets
{
    param(
    [Parameter(Position = 0, ParameterSetName = "NameName")] 
    [Parameter(Position = 0, ParameterSetName = "NameId")] 
    [string] $A_by_Name, 

    [Parameter(Position = 0, ParameterSetName = "IdName")] 
    [Parameter(Position = 0, ParameterSetName = "IdId")] 
    [int] $A_by_Id,

    [Parameter(Position = 1, ParameterSetName = "NameName")] 
    [Parameter(Position = 1, ParameterSetName = "IdName")] 
    [string] $B_by_Name,

    [Parameter(Position = 1, ParameterSetName = "NameId")] 
    [Parameter(Position = 1, ParameterSetName = "IdId")] 
    [int] $B_by_Id
    )


    "ParametetSetName is $($PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName)"
}
```

This outputs:

```
Test-ParameterSets : Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters.
At line:25 char:1
+ Test-ParameterSets
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Test-ParameterSets], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmbiguousParameterSet,Test-ParameterSets
```

You usually use ParamaterSetName when you have different behavior or use different parameters depending on which parameter set the user of your function is using.  The rule is correct.  You can help PowerShell determine which parameterset is in use by using the `DefaultParameterSetName` property of the `CmdletBinding` attribute.

Comment: Only if you call it without specifying two parameters. If you call `Test-ParameterSets a b` it outputs `NameName`. If you call `Test-ParameterSets 0 1` it outputs `IdId`.

Comment: Yes but PowerShell can figure that out. Two strings can only be NameName and int,int can only be IdId.  There's no ambiguity. PowerShell also uses the type of the argument for resolution which may be leading to the confusion.  You need a "unique" parameter in a parameter set when all the types are the same as well. In that event, PowerShell has nothing else to fall back upon to determine which parameter set has been selected.